# Dimension of space of $4\times 4$ matrices that centralize a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem description:

Let A be an $4\times 4$  complex matrix, determine the largest possible dimension of the subspace $S_A=\{B \in M_n (C)|AB=BA\}$.

My answer is 10. Because all commuting matrices are triangulable, so the largest number of the unit matrices $E_{ij}$ equal to the basis that spans an upper triangular matrix.

Is my answer right? Or can you help to offer a proof.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not 10 in the special case that $A$ is the identity matrix, so maybe you need to provide more details of your line of thought?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, all matrices are triangularizable; your argument doesn't make much sense. What do $E_{ij}$ have to do with anything? Note that $E_{ij}A$ is the matrix whose $i$th row is the $j$th row of $A$, and $0$s elsewhere, whereas $AE_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $j$th column is the $i$th column of $A$ and $0$s elsewhere. There are very few matrices $A$ for which $AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more generic answer...

Suppose $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$, with corresponding right and left eigenvectors $v_1,...,v_n$ and $u_1^*,...,u_n^*$ respectively. Then it is easy to see that the linear operator $L_A(B) = AB-BA$ has $n^2$ eigenvalues $\mu_{ij} = \lambda_i-\lambda_j$ with corresponding linearly independent eigenvectors $v_i u_j^*$. The kernel of $L_A$ corresponds to the span of the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\mu_{ii} = 0$. Consequently, $\dim \ker L_A = n$.

Since $S_A = \ker L_A$, we have that, in a generic sense, $\dim S_A = n$.

Comment: great answer, though it is beyond my level. thanks.

Comment: May I trouble you with an explanation of how one can see that $L_A(B) = AB-BA$ has $n^2$ eigenvalues? The characteristic polynomial still has degree $n$ like for linear transformations that map to $K^{n}$ where $K$ is a field, so I don't understand! I realise that $L_A$ belongs to a $n^2$ dimensional space but it doesn't help. Thank you

Comment: $L_A$ maps from the space of matrices to the space matrices, and the dimension of that space is $n^2$, hence there are $n^2$ eigenvalues (counting multiplicity).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for the *bigest* possible dimension. This is attained for $A=E_4$ with $S_A=M_4(\mathbb C)$ which has dimension $16$.
Here $E_4$ denotes the identity matrix. Alternatively we could also choose $A=0$ and still get $S_A=M_4(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Surely you mean for $A=0$? (I'm not exactly what you mean by $E_4$.)

Comment: how do you reach the answer of E4? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @user30114 He probably means, as I mentioned above, the identity matrix. *Everything* commutes with it.